# If else statement for showing a different type from Schema Object

Tags: if-statement, shopify

I have two different types in my object, i am trying to show only one on my homepage section video text.

My code goes like this

```
{%if id == 'video_url' %}           
<video style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" controls="true">             <source src="{{ section.settings.video_url }}" type="video/mp4"/>           </video> 
{%elsif id == 'video_urlt'%}           <video style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="">             <source src="{{ section.settings.video_urlt }}" type="video/mp4"/>           </video> 
{%endif %}
```

and my object in  schema is defined like this

```
 "type": "video_url",
        "id": "video_url",
        "default": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9VUPq3SxOc",
        "label": "Video url youtube",
        "info": "Upload your Youtube video to Shopify then paste the url here",
        "accept": ["youtube"]


      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "video_urlt",
        "default": "Upload your video from files",
        "label": "Video url uploaded",
        "info": "Upload your video to Shopify then paste the url here"


      },
```

I tried diffrent else if and also changed default properties. I want to have only one div with correct video format on the frontend.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What happens if you just print the id `{{id}}`. Is it the value you expect?

Comment: nothing much, still no output on the frontend.

Comment: So the problem is in the variable id not in the if

Comment: I managed to display with unless section.settings.video_urlt == blank -